# Recovering LTC coin sent to a BTC address

Tags: wallet, litecoin, private-key, private-key-export, cross-chain-recovery

I have mistakenly sent LTC coin(Using bittrex) to my BTC wallet(Zebpay). I have not received the coins yet.

The transaction is showing 6+ confirmations on blockcypher and not showing anything in blockchain.info.

Following to this, Bittrex has advised me to research how to remove a private key from a Bitcoin address and import it into a LTC wallet to recover these coins or contact someone from the LTC community for help.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: do you have "private keys export feature" in your Zebpay BTC wallet?

Comment: no, how can we import the private key through a different source?

Comment: You should get your private keys to spend stucked coins. But I am not sure that Zebpay would help you in it

Answer (score 1):

I sent my LTC to my Trezor BTC wallet. There is a Trezor recovery function that will recover it if it was sent to a Trezor address.

Hope that helps anyone with a Trezor out!

Comment: every serious exchange should have a feature like this IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem:

> [How is my Zebpay wallet secured?](https://zebpay.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201287382-How-is-my-Zebpay-wallet-secured-)
>   "[...] Zebpay is a hosted bitcoin wallet. That is the private keys of your bitcoins are with Zebpay. We manage the security of your wallet. [...]"

The only way to get your LTC is to contact Zebpay and state your problem:
https://zebpay.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205420211-Contact-Us

Comment: Zebpay has given up and have told me that they cant help

Comment: I'm sorry but then there is nothing you can do... Maybe never use Zebpay again and give them bad reviews but that doesn't really help.

Answer (score -1):

Hate to be the bearer of bad news but those puppies are gone.  Two entirely different blockchains with entirely different wallet address formats.  Hopefully it wasnt a large amount.

Comment: the blockchain format itself is the same. address format is the same also (and this is the cause of such mistakes). Zebpay is holding private keys and/or has a knowledge how to get them. But I do not think that they will do such things for mistakenly sent coins

Comment: Do u have that blockcypher link to the tx?

Comment: Also found this obscure link.

Comment: https://amp.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6sfnl2/segwit_has_been_locked_in_congratulations_everyone/dleu77d/

Comment: yes i have the blockcypher link..can it help?